# What is counterpart of SIGKILL(in POSIX) in WIN32

Tags: visual-studio, events, signals

What is counterpart of SIGKILL(in POSIX) in WIN32. VS cannot recognize SIGKILL.

Answer (score 2):

API function [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28VS.85%29.aspx) is probably closest. SIGKILL is special anyway in POSIX and not really a signal. You need to open the process handle with OpenProcess and close it afterwards with CloseHandle.